# Project of a capacitive finger to test finger Print sensor

Tags: electrically-conductive

How can I choose the best material to use in a project of a "capacitive finger"?

The capacitive finger will be used to simulate a human finger , and will be used to test Finger Print Sensor or Touch Screen.

I understand that the best probably is the material more similar to our human body in terms of capacitance. Is it correct?

Comment: Are trying to use a capacitive touch sensor or finger print ID?

Comment: https://www.testdevlab.com/blog/2017/07/how-we-built-a-robot-for-automated-manual-mobile-testing/